# HTML form won't send data to new URL :\

Tags: html, forms

I have no idea why the form is not sending data to `exp.php` after clicking the button. It just calls the url but GET and POST won't submit any data:

```
<form id="sendrating" action="exp.php" method="post">
    <input id="score" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"/>
    <input id="group" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="randomid" type="hidden" value="">
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your inputs don't have name attributes, try this:

```
<form id="sendrating" action="exp.php" method="post">
<input id="score" name="score" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"/>
<input id="group" name="group" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="randomid" name="randomid" type="hidden" value="">
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" id="ok">
```

Answer (score 1):

Input tags only submit their data as part of forms if they have a `name` attribute. Just having an `id` isn't good enough.